# Perl regex question

Tags: regex, perl

how to build a perl regular expresion that would match a pattern like this

Starts with XXX and ends with AAA

(1) within one line
(2) spanning many lines

Please help, i'm new to regular expresions :)

Comment: See perlre: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only within a single line:

```
/XXX.*AAA/
```

Spanning multiple lines:

```
/XXX.*AAA/s
```

Use an additional `/g` to match all occurrences.

Answer (score 4):

single line:

```
/XXX.*?AAA/  # example "foo XXX bar AAA egg" will match "XXX bar AAA"
```

multiline:

```
/XXX.*?AAA/s
```

the question mark `?` determines greediness of your expression. If you need last `AAA` then you should remove `?`. If you need first AAA after XXX then it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

So:

```
/^XXX.*AAA$/s
```

The `s` modifier treats the input as a single line (`.` matches also a newline).

[Reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't necessarily need *one* regex. For single line:

```
say 'I matched.' if m/^AAA/ and m/XXX$/;
```

For multiline:

```
say 'I matched.' if m/\AAAA/m and m/XXX\z/m;
```

- `\A` `=>`  absolute beginning (`^` is just the beginning of *a* line.)
- `\z` `=>`  absolute ending (although you can use `\Z` if you want the end and don't care
  if the record separator is there or not.
- `/m` `=>` multiline switch

However there is also `substr` which works for either, with exact strings:

```
say 'I matched.' if substr( $_, 0, 3 ) eq 'AAA' and substr( $_, -3 ) eq 'XXX';
```